# How to share one IP address among VMs on a Hyper-V Server?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-networking, hyper-v-manager

My dedicated server came with one IP address.  I installed Hyper-V Server 2019 on it, and I want to simultaneously run multiple VMs, each running Windows Server 20xx Standard.  I'll need to be able to remote desktop to each VM, as well as the host.  I'm thinking I could change the port number that each VM listens to for RDC (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/change-listening-port).  Would that work?

Next, for outbound TCP/IP from the VMs, since that uses ephemeral port numbers, what happens if 2 VMs try to make connections from the same port number?  I know the odds are low, given how large the range is of ephemeral port numbers, but what would happen, and if it's bad, what could I do about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a NAT network.

NAT Network helps Virtual Machines to access the External Host/Virtual Machines using Host computer IP address and port through Internal Switch (NAT Switch).

[image]

[image]

For more details about Hyper-V NAT network, you can refer to the following article:

[Hyper-V Virtual Switch Using NAT Setup](https://www.vembu.com/blog/hyper-v-virtual-switch-using-nat-setup/)

[Set up a NAT network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network)

Comment: +1 Nice post. :)

Comment: Thanks.  Nicely presented.  I'm unclear about incoming requests.  Say I have 2 VMs, and I want to be able to browse TO each from the outside, perhaps the first to the default port 80, and the second to port 8080.  What PowerShell commands can tell NAT that incoming requests to <real IP>:80 get routed to <VM1's local IP>:80, and that requests to <real IP>:8080 get routed to <VM2's local IP>:80?